# WebMatrix internal search engine

Tags: c#, webmatrix

I've wrriten a code which searchs the database but i don't know why when i search for some specific keywords it'll show other links which are unrelated. here's the code and the result.

```
Page.Title = "Catalog Search";
var db = Database.Open("Shopping");
var searchWords = Request["searchTerm"].Split(' ');
IEnumerable<dynamic> result = Enumerable.Empty<string>();
var sqlSelect = "SELECT ProductId, ProductTitle FROM Products WHERE " +
"ProductTitle LIKE @0";
foreach(var word in searchWords)
{
result = result.Concat(db.Query(sqlSelect, "%" + word + "%").ToList());
}
```

so i searched for "Samsung LCD" and here's the result.

```
Samsung - 15" Series 9 Ultrabook Laptop
Samsung - Galaxy Tab 2 7.0
Samsung - 32" Class - LCD
Samsung - 32" Class - LCD
```

i've seen a php code which is exactly what i want but unfortunately i don't know how to convert it. here's the php code.

```
$searchTerms = explode(' ', $bucketsearch);
$searchTermBits = array();
foreach ($searchTerms as $term) {
    $term = trim($term);
    if (!empty($term)) {
        $searchTermBits[] = "bucketname LIKE '%$term%'";
    }
}

...

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM buckets WHERE ".implode(' AND ', $searchTermBits).");
```

and the result of the php search code.

```
SELECT * FROM buckets WHERE bucketname LIKE '%apple%' AND bucketname LIKE '%and%' AND bucketname LIKE '%pear%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the liberty of adding a few null checks and such, but the code for C# would pretty much look like this:

```
// make sure search terms are passed in, and remove blank entries
var searchTerms = Request["searchTerms"] == null ? 
                    new string[] {} : 
                    Request["searchTerms"].Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// build the list of query items using parameterization
var searchTermBits = new List<string>();
for (var i=0; i<searchTerms.Length; i++) {
    searchTermBits.Add("bucketname LIKE @" + i);
}

// create your sql command using a join over the array
var query = "SELECT * FROM buckets";
if (searchTerms.Length > 0) {
  query += " WHERE " + string.Join(" AND ", searchTermBits);  
} 

// ask the database using a lambda to add the %
var db = Database.Open("StarterSite");
var results = db.Query(query, searchTerms.Select(x => "%" + x + "%").ToArray());

// enjoy!
Response.Write(results.Count());
```

Let me know if you run into any more trouble!

Comment: Thanks Justin. That's splendid